# "g++" is not recognized as an internal or external command, MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, mingw

On my computer I have Windows 7 x86. I installed MinGW, I wrote the path but when I go in cmd.exe and write g++ -v it says:

```
"g++" is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

But when I write the make -v command it recognizes it. I need this for school, I work in Eclipse, I even installed the latest java(I saw it must be installed).

Comment: You need to set the environment `PATH` to include the directory of mingw's `bin` directory if you want o use `gcc.exe` or `g++.exe` in `cmd`.

Comment: run 'path' or 'echo %PATH% in cmd.exe prompt. Check the path carefully. Is it 'C:\mingw\bin;' ?

Comment: C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin this is what i have i path. and i checked the path and it's correct. and in the file you can find g++.exe

Comment: Did you start a new cmd shell? Is your path global or localized to a single command shell?

Comment: so I tried to go specifically to the location of the g++.exe and when i tried to run it from there it worked but when i run from a new cmd without going specifically there it gives the same error, and I entered eclipse and the hello world build in programm doesn't work.

Comment: Hey, did you restart the computer after setting the PATH? That's needed even if the PTH variable shows the correct value.

Comment: @user462608: That's absolutely **not** needed. However, the setting only takes effect for *processes started after the change*. If you change the setting and start new `cmd.exe` via start menu, it will have the new setting, but window already open will not.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius It's nonsense to restart the computer after setting an environment variable in the Control Panel. If you're uncertain what you do you can logoff and logon again. But it's just necessary to start a new process that will be invoked with the change you did in the Control Panel. So you should start a new explorer if you start your batch file containing the `g++` call. Or you start a new command line prompt. That's all. "Restart the computer", sic. When the `echo %PATH%` shows the correct value the value ist correct, isn't it?

Answer (score 16):

Seeing that the make command works fine, I think you forgot to mark the `mingw-gcc-g++` package in the MinGW Installation Manager.

Run the MinGW Installation Manager again and mark `mingw-gcc-g++` for installation and press `Apply Changes`

Comment: Thanks a lot! The whole question is useless without this answer.

Answer (score 13):

You have to modify environment variables. Do the following:

- From the desktop, right-click Computer and click Properties.
- From the Computer Properties window, click Change Settings
- In the System Properties window which opens up, click on the Advanced tab.
- In the Advanced section, click the Environment Variables button.
- Finally, in the Environment Variables window (as shown below), highlight the Path variable in the Systems Variable section and click the Edit button. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you wish the computer to access. Each different directory is separated with a semicolon as shown below.

  `C:\Program Files;C:\Winnt;C:\Winnt\System32`

Additionally you may refer to [this link](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in Sublime..

```
Right click on my computer
Advanced system settings
Environment variables
in system variables, change path to location of '...\MinGW\bin'
```

Example: D:\work\sublime\MinGW\bin

Comment: By "change path" do you mean "add to the path", because just changing it will make g++ work but break everything else

Answer (score 0):

1. Just go to the search bar a situated at bottom left of your task bar
2. Search for environmental variables, after you click on the "Edit the system environmental variables"
3. Click on Environmental variables
4. Select Path(double click) , Add new path
5. Paste your Mingw-bin path , something like-"C:\MinGW\bin"
6. Restart your computer
7. Your gcc/gcc+ should be working fine now :)

Answer (score -1):

**How to Get the G++ Complier working Step by Step**

--

If you dont have MINSYS you can download from here

in the Down load the installer section

https://www.msys2.org/

--

Then download MinGW

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/

and install ALL packages

--

Now add both Minsys and  MinGW you your C: folder

--

Then Open Minsys there should be a mingw 32 folder and a mingw 64 folder

Delete all files in both those folders

Then go to MinGW ,

Take everything inside the mingw32 folder and paste it inside of the minsys mingw32 folder

Then Take everything inside the mingw64 folder and paste it inside of the minsys mingw64 folder

--

Now your minsys is ready to go.

--

Now you can update your PATHS so your computer can find and use it

--

Go to Settings > system about >> Advanced System Settings >> Enviroment Variables >> Click Path in top "User Variables for ***" Section (This will set theses PATHS only for this Computer User) >> Then click on the ADD button and paste **C:\msys64\mingw64\bin**

--

Important Note: After you entered in your PATHS in the Enviroment variables you should click **TWO** ok buttons, to Activate the edits.

So Click ok.

When that pop up closes that you entered in your path make sure to click OK AGAIN on the Original Enviroment Variables page, so that you finally set your new changes.

***If you do not do this your changes will not be actually saved.***

then you can open CMD ( if you already have it open make sure to close it first and then open it again fresh)

Then Type

**gcc --version**

Then

**g++ --version**

Then

**gdb --version**

if they all say there is a version **installed you are good to go!**

--

**This fixed it for me, You can do it!**

--

Additional link Help

[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#:~:text=If%20you%20don't%20see,website%20to%20install%20Mingw%2Dw64](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#:%7E:text=If%20you%20don%27t%20see,website%20to%20install%20Mingw%2Dw64).

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you bastardize MSYS2 like this? Why not install MinGW from its package manager? Or, if you don't like it for some reason, just add an external MinGW to the PATH, rather than overwriting parts of MSYS2 filesystem with it.