# Installing Python Fancy Impute Module for K-Nearest Neighbors Imputation of Null Values

Tags: python, installation, g++, python-module

I am using a 64bit Windows 10 machine.

I am trying to install the [fancy impute module](https://github.com/hammerlab/fancyimpute) to do K-Nearest Neighbors Imputation of null values in a data set.

I have had to separately install `cvxopt` with

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/eswears cvxopt
```

and Keras using

```
pip install keras
```

When I write into python from the command prompt

```
[Anaconda2] C:\Users\path>python
>>> import fancyimpute
```

I receive the below errors (I have truncated the error messages but can show full errors on request)

```
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected...
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command...
```

**EDIT**
To remedy the problem, I have downloaded MinGW and followed the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741568/g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-mingw), but am still receiving the same error.

My questions are:

(1) is there another way around the error messages I am receiving?

(2) is there a python module that also does K-Nearest Neighbors Imputation of null values?

Comment: the error means you don't have g++, you can install it with MinGW - http://www.mingw.org/wiki/howto_install_the_mingw_gcc_compiler_suite

Comment: I have already installed MinGW and followed the directions in the link I included in my question. Apologies if that is unclear. I will edit my question to highlight that

Answer (score 0):

Is there an error beyond the g++ warning? I may be wrong, but I was under the impression that Theano will default to slower implementations in the absence of a compiler. Since fancyimpute's. KNN implementation doesn't actually use Theano then you should still be able to use that portion of the library.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install before the librairie "ecos".

If there is a problem to import the ecos library, simply download the ecos package corresponding to the configuration of the PC from the site: "http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs "
Then, type on the terminal at the download address:
"Pip install ecos‑2.0.4‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl"

Good luck