# 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"hi"<<endl;   
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Sublime text 3, and I am getting this error:

> error-
>   'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   [Finished in 0.0s]

Comment: It means that you haven't installed `g++` correctly.

Comment: Which operating system are you using ?.

Comment: @Shravan40 the message looks like crap windows messages: so, windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["g++" is not recognized as an internal or external command, MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741568/g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-mingw)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to set `g++` to your system path.

You can refer to this:
http://stephencoakley.com/2015/01/21/guide-setting-up-a-simple-c-development-environment-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while running the code from command line. And found out that I messed up with MinGW installation. So I reinstalled it,

Do this while installing MinGW ----

1. After downloading, install MinGW and wait for the “MinGW Installation Manager” to show up.
2. When the “MinGW Installation Manager” shows up, click on mingw32-gcc-g++ then select “Mark for Installation”
3. In the menu at the top left corner, click on “Installation  > Apply Changes”
4. Wait and allow to install completely. Ensure you have a stable internet connection during this process.

when it is done, then edit the environment 'Path' Variable as stated in other answer.

In short I followed [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-compile-your-c-code-in-visual-studio-code/)

Comment: After installing visual studio (which is massive) and failing. I tried this and it worked immediaely....  the only issue that i have with this is that the user needs to press `ctrl + alt + n` to run code and not the usual `f5` or `ctrl + f5`....

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's easily fixed by two steps, as below:

1. Set the environment variable:

   `C:/MinGW/bin`
2. Paste the following code in the "launch.json":

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Compiler",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:/MinGW/bin",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: this gives:  `C:\MinGW\bin` does not exist even though the folder is there and i did a copy / paste (to ensure no typo's).

Answer (score 0):

Open mingw-w64 folder
click on mingw32->i686-w64-mingw32->bin
copy this path and set this path in your system environment variables

Answer (score 0):

If you keep getting this error, make sure you set up MinGW in Path variable, not separated user\system variables: [pic link on imgur here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDG2T.jpg)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32183540)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is first of all ensure you have download minGW properly you can refer from this site https://www.msys2.org/ , Be sure to follow all the steps inorder for it to install completely (ps:it takes a while),, after that you can go to environment system variables via settings and a new path C:\msys64\mingw64\bin or wherever your msys64 file might be stored. Hope this helps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32307583)

Answer (score -2):

Check if you have installed g++ by typing `g++ --version`. If you already have g++ compiler installed, just hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save the changes you made, then run the code.