# Getting: 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to run C++ on Visual Studio code it outputs 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I've tried resetting my computer many times. I also got MinGW for the C++ complier. I've tried looking for solution's on the web and on here but could not find any.

Comment: Your bug is probably in your .json files. This should help you set them up: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: ***Can anyone help with this?*** You have to show your configuration. It's difficult to help when you show very little.

Comment: ***it outputs 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command*** That means that g++ is not installed where you told Visual Studio Code it was installed. Depending on your .json files you may be able to set the full path or it expects g++ to be in one of the folders of your windows PATH environment variable.

Comment: `tasks.json` contains the settings for how to build using g++. This is explained in the first link.

Comment: ok thanks this helped a lot I did some more research and your helped did it

Comment: Exact duplicate: ['g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652211/g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or). Please always search for error messages here - there are about 500 for this one.

Answer (score 2):

If set up properly, VSCode will usually create available profiles for you. The following content is based on Windows 10, and it's simpler on other platforms.

1. Install `MinGW` or `MinGW-w64`. Make sure the `bin` folder is in `PATH`
   [image: mingw bin in path]
   [image: check commands in cmd]
2. In VSCode Folder/Workspace, delete or backup all profiles in `.vscode`. If `.vscode` is not existing, create a empty `.vscode`.
   [image: empty.vscode]
3. Open a example file such as `hello.c`, run it and follow the guides: `C++(GDB/LLDB)` >>> `gcc.exe...`.
   [image: running guides]

If all goes well, VSCode will cerate `lauch.json` and `tasks.json` correctly. Then you can run or debug your c/cpp file now.
[image: all goes well]