# how can I run a c++ problem in vscode and with a txt file input

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a problem that gets input from a txt file in vscode and I don't know what to write in terminal. I'm using windows10. My program has as output an other file which is created by running my solution. Here is my code. Thanks
[the parts that i use the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr62B.png)

Answer (score 0):

Download those extensions to run a program on VSCode

[C/C++ Extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)

[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

Afterwards, you can run your program with `ALT + CTRL + N`

Comment: it still doesn't run 
it says this:
[Running] cd "c:\Users\nefik\hashcode final\" && g++ hashpel.h -o hashpel && "c:\Users\nefik\hashcode final\"hashpel
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.035 seconds

Comment: Have you installed MinGW (the C++ compiler)? After installation, have you added `g++` to your environment path? You can check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38652211/11067496) for more.